# How to write a function for this fractal?

Tags: functions, fractals

How can I write a function to describe this fractal's Nth stage?

[image]

I know it should be equal to 1 for some x and 0 for the rest but can't figure the math.
I don't know if my drawing is good enough. But I think what I mean is clear. I need to use it in a computer code. and thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks to me like the $n^{\text{th}}$ label is associated with the $n^{\text{th}}$ level approximation of the Cantor set. In between the labeled pieces, it looks like you've got the complementary intervals that have been removed up to that point. I don't know if the fractal is suppose to be the Cantor set, the complement, or some combination.

Comment: @MarkMcClure: (+1) Looks to me like successive approximations to the graph of the characteristic function of the Cantor set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of a formula, a recursive specification is more natural, something like:

```
double cantor(double x, double a, double b, unsigned int depth)
{
  if (depth == 0) // bottom of recursion
    return 0;

  else if (x <= a + (1.0/3)*(b - a)) // x in first third of interval
    return cantor(x, a, a + (1.0/3)*(b - a), depth - 1);

  else if (a + (2.0/3)*(b - a) <= x) // x in last third of interval
    return cantor(x, a + (2.0/3)*(b - a), b, depth - 1);

  else // middle third
    return 1;
}
```

Start with the interval $[a, b]$ on the $x$-axis and recursively perform the operation:

> If an interval lies on the $x$-axis, trisect it and push the middle third up one unit.

The call `cantor(x, 0, 1, 6)`, for example, starts with $[0, 1]$ and returns the height at $x$ after six iterations of the preceding operation.

Comment: This is amazing and is exactly what I was looking for. Bravo and thanks. :)